# How to groupy and count the occurances of each element of an array column in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, aggregate

I have a spark dataframe with the following columns:

```
   id   interests          user_id
    1    [dance, music]        k01
    1    [song, music].        k02
    1    [dance, cricket].     k03
    2    [cricket, music]      k02
    2    [song, music].        k04
    2    [dance, cricket].     k03
```

I want to aggregate it such that it looks like this:

```
id  interests    Count
1    dance        2
1    music        2
1    song         1
1    cricket      1
2    dance        1
2    music        2
2    song         1
2    cricket      2
```

If a label is not present in any id than the count should come as zero.

Comment: `F.explode` the arrays into rows and then do a `groupBy` on the interests and id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `explode` to explode `interests` array & then use `groupBy` & `count` functions.

```
>>> df.show()
+---+----------------+-------+
| id|       interests|user_id|
+---+----------------+-------+
|  1|  [dance, music]|    k01|
|  1|   [song, music]|    k02|
|  1|[dance, cricket]|    k03|
|  2|[cricket, music]|    k02|
|  2|   [song, music]|    k04|
|  2|[dance, cricket]|    k03|
+---+----------------+-------+
```

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df \
.withColumn("interests",F.explode(F.col("interests"))) \
.groupBy(F.col("id"),F.col("interests")) \
.agg(F.count("*").alias("count")) \
.show()
+---+---------+-----+
| id|interests|count|
+---+---------+-----+
|  2|  cricket|    2|
|  2|    dance|    1|
|  2|     song|    1|
|  1|    music|    2|
|  2|    music|    2|
|  1|  cricket|    1|
|  1|    dance|    2|
|  1|     song|    1|
+---+---------+-----+
```